# Editorpart positioning at the bottom

Tags: 2010, web-part, development

I created my own custom editor part for my web part.

But when I add it to the web part, it displays by default at the top, what i would like to have is to position it at the bottom.

Anyona has any idea, how to achieve that?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of what you have now?

Comment: updated the post with screenshot